# How to change permissions to mysql pid file

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

By default mysql creates pid file as `-rw-rw---- mysql:mysql mysql.pid`. Is there any way to change those permissions? I need `o+r` for monitoring purposes.

Of course I could add sticky bit for directory above and change group ownership but if it could be changed somewhere in settings it would be the cleanest solution.

I'm running mysql 5.5 if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need. You can check the existence of the file without changing the permissions:

```
if [ -f /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ]; then     echo "mysqld running"; fi
```

If that's not good enough you can check the pid (i.e. the *contents* of the file) directly:

```
ps -U mysql | grep mysqld | cut -f1 -d' '
```

Comment: True, I just wanted to skip a need for rewriting monitoring plugin. My question is still valid :) First check is not good enough as pid file will be there after fatal crash of mysql.

Comment: so how will being able to read the contents of the file change that?

Comment: Plugin verifies if process is still alive. I just had ready plugin. That's all. I already fixed it but problem still exists. And I'm very curious if there is an easy solution to this.

Comment: @Kalavan - how did you fix it?

Comment: @Ricke James - I fixed monitoring plugin. It now finds PID from ps but that does not change a problem with changing permissions to mysql pid file. I'm still curious if someone knows the solution for my question.